# Attempt at showing the structure of a proof of : " A well ordered set is totally ordered"

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, logic

I tried to prove in a natural deduction style the basic ( almost trivial maybe ) theorem on well ordered sets : " Any well ordered set is totally ordered".

Would you please tell me which objections could be made to this proof. Any comment is welcome.

I think I used " consructive dilemma" in the subordinate derivation. Is this correct?

Which justification could I bring to : " a and be belong to A, therefore {a,b} is a subset of A" ?  ( Is a set theoretic axiom required here?)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the proof.

You need the axiom of pairing to form the set $\{a,b\}$.